# How to call a function only Once in Python

Tags: python

here I want to call web service function only once throughout the program.
how to accomplish this anybody suggest me

```
import sys,os

def web_service(macid):
        # do something

if "__name__" = "__main__" :
      web_service(macid)
```

Comment: `"__name__" = "__main__"` will not work. You might want to do `__name__ == "__main__"`. Assignment operator (`=`) is not the same as equality operator (`==`). Also check [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html), it is not `"__name__"`.

Comment: @thefourtheye I think you meant `__name__ == "__main__"`

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: @thefourtheye  i want to call webservice function only once.how to achieve this . Can you suggest me,if __name__ == '__main__": that i know

Comment: Generic solution: Once it has been called, set a variable to `true` or something, check if that variable is `true`, `return` immediately. Or you'll have to give a few more details about why you want this.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.2 or later you can use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Answer (score 10):

This is how I would to that:

```
i_run_once_has_been_run = False

def i_run_once(macid):
    global i_run_once_has_been_run

    if i_run_once_has_been_run:
        return

    # do something

    i_run_once_has_been_run = True
```

@Vaulstein's decorator function would work too, and may even be a bit more pythonic - but it seems like a bit overkill to me.

Comment: What if you have two functions you only want to run once?

Comment: @PeterWood then you would use two globals, I guess. I think at that point the decorator makes sense, but for a single function just a global boolean is best.

Comment: What would you name the other global?

Comment: Good point - see my edit. I guess if `i_run_once_also()` were in play we would name the global `i_run_once_also_has_been_run`. But again, I think the decorator solution is better there.

Comment: Rather than a global, perhaps use an attribute (`i_run_once.has_been_run = True`), and test it with `getattr(i_run_once, 'has_been_run', False)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using class,

```
class CallOnce(object):
    called = False

    def web_service(cls, macid):
        if cls.called:
            print "already called"
            return
        else:
            # do stuff
            print "called once"
            cls.called = True
            return


macid = "123"
call_once_object = CallOnce()
call_once_object.web_service(macid)
call_once_object.web_service(macid)
call_once_object.web_service(macid)
```

Result is,

```
I have no name!@sla-334:~/stack_o$ python once.py 
called once
already called
already called
```